# Change default audio device on Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, audio

I want to be able to change the default audio output device on Windows 7 programatically using C# (and probably some underlying Win32 API calls, as well). I've already done my homework, and I've heard a lot of mixed comments from different sources, so I wanted to ask this question again to get a straight answer. Is this actually possible (through *any* means)? If so, how would I go about doing this?

And please do not suggest a solution with "AutoIt" or some other similar program... this is a C#/.NET-specific question.

Comment: Good odds that you'll get just more mixed comments from yet another source.  Here's one: only a user selects the audio device she wants to listen to.

Comment: +1 I was thinking of programming this myself. I really hate switching between my headphones and HDMI output.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just in case anyone stumbles across this thread in the future... here's some C++ code that'll do it by calling some undocumented Win32 APIs. This can be compiled into an EXE and then called silently from a .NET application, so you could build a .NET program around this code.

http://web.archive.org/web/20190317012739/http://www.daveamenta.com/2011-05/programmatically-or-command-line-change-the-default-sound-playback-device-in-windows-7/

Comment: It was working for Win 8.1 but unfortunatly it is not working anymore with windows 10, any solutions?

Comment: You can check my answer for something that works with W10 !

Comment: this link is dead

Answer (score 17):

A little up-to-date answer, which is **compatible with Windows 10**.

This program is able to do it in a beautiful manner (hotkey to switch between pre-selected devices) and is written on C# :
[SoundSwitch on GitHub](https://github.com/Belphemur/SoundSwitch)

Some reverse engineering should get you there (for my use this program was just perfect as it is).

It makes use of that library (same author) which is in C++ :
[AudioEndpointLibrary on GitHub](https://github.com/Belphemur/AudioEndPointLibrary)

So if you know C++ (which I don't enough), you might go further in the analysis of how it works. Or just use the library like SoundSwitch does.

Comment: Just a note about SoundSwitch: sometimes it is unreliable as it sets audio devices as communication devices instead of audio output and sometimes devices are forgotten from its system tray menu. But it's a start.