# How to change from rear to front audio input?

Tags: c#, audio, input, audio-device

Is there a way in c# to change rear and front audio input volume or default device?

I've tried looking for existing answers, but I can't find any information for this.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default audio device on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179335/change-default-audio-device-on-windows-7)

Comment: No . this code is for changing audio device. I'm using the same audio device (pc sound card). what Iwant to do is to switch between front panel to rear panel